# Core Data example, Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ipad, ios, core-data

I am novice at iOS and XCode, and am working through a Core Data tutorial and am really stumped. I continually get the error in the error logs of the following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 235, iPhone OS 4.2 (iPad/8C134)
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x010a6be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00e9b5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0105f628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
        3   Foundation                          0x000b447b -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
        4   UIKit                               0x00336a0f -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8424
        5   UIKit                               0x00325f81 -[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 56
        6   SimpleRes                           0x00002496 -[RootViewController addReservation] + 465
        7   UIKit                               0x002b9a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
        8   UIKit                               0x004c7167 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
        9   UIKit                               0x002b9a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
        10  UIKit                               0x003481b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
        11  UIKit                               0x0034a647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
        12  UIKit                               0x003491f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
        13  UIKit                               0x002de0d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
        14  UIKit                               0x002bf37a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
        15  UIKit                               0x002c4732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
        16  GraphicsServices                    0x018bda36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x01088064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x00fe86f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x00fe5983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x00fe5240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x00fe5161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
        22  GraphicsServices                    0x018bc268 GSEventRunModal + 217
        23  GraphicsServices                    0x018bc32d GSEventRun + 115
        24  UIKit                               0x002c842e UIApplicationMain + 1160
        25  SimpleRes                           0x00001ab0 main + 102
        26  SimpleRes                           0x00001a41 start + 53
)
```

Here is my addReservation code:

```
-(void)addReservation{

    // Create and configure a new instance of the Event entity.
    Reservations *reservation = (Reservations *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Reservations" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [reservation setEnd_Time: [[NSDate alloc]init]];
    [reservation setReservation_Date:[[NSDate alloc]init]];
    [reservation setStart_Time:[NSDate date]];
    [reservation setParty_Size: [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
    [reservation setPhone_Number: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1234567890]];
    [reservation setName: @"Keith"];
    [reservation setNotes: @"He's really hot!"];
    [reservation setPerson_Responsible: @"Lisa"];
    [reservation setTables_Excluded: @"3,5,8"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        }

    [resArray insertObject:reservation atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

I believe that my resArray is not getting the data from the method that I input in programatically, but I am not sure, and I am not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you follow the Apple iOS Core Data tutorial, the files that are generated by the template has the line return 0; for the numberOfSectionsInTable delegate method. Just change that line to return 1 and it should be good then.

Answer (score 30):

I would take a look at your implementation of

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

The error you specified occurs when the value returned from numberOfRowsInSection does not equal the previous value plus the number of rows you added using insertRowsAtIndexPaths.  If your implementation of numberOfRowsInSection is using [myArray count], then make sure that the array instance used is the same one into which you are adding the reservation entry.  If you have not implemented this method, then that would be your problem.  Here is an example of how that method should look:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [resArray count];
}
```

As a backup, you can add log statements that list the size of the array before and after the addition, and inside of the numberOfRowsInSection function.

Comment: If you're dumb like me, the array might be null. :)

Answer (score 11):

The order that you delete/insert from the tableView and you delete/insert from the underlying datasource can be important. Apple documentation has updating the view first and then the datasource. However, deleting/inserting from the view internally calls `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` which, if you're like me, returns the `count` of the underlying datasource. Because this has not changed, the runtime will complain and crash. So remove from your datasource first, then the view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [recentImages count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Delete from underlying data source first!
    recentImages = [recentImages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Then perform the action on the tableView
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {   
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];        
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }

    // Finally, reload data in view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: The call to `reloadData` at the end is redundant. You should either use `begin`/`endUpdates` to sync the table to your underlying data *OR* `reloadData` to just reload everything (which is more costly CPU wise and probably won't look as nice to the user). But there's no need to do both. I've submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks as if you are inserting the object before you accually make the changes to it.  I could be wrong as i am also a novice!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];



   }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; 

        // Delete the object that was swiped
        YourTableName *objectToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", objectToDelete.fieldname);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject: objectToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];



        [self.tableView reloadData];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];


          }
}
```

This works when deleting and adding records to a core data table with fetchedResultsController.